# Swift give height to an element based on screen size

Tags: iphone, swift

I have an element in Swift

```
let background_image: UIImageView = {
    let view = UIImageView()
    view.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "basketball")
    view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()
    background_image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    background_image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
```

And the problem is when user's device is Iphone 5 then 200 is too big.How can i resize the height based on the device.If it's Iphone 5 then make it 150 else 200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can it be proportional? I like that. That way, it ain't so hard:

```
background_image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.height / 4).isActive = true
```

If you really want it device based, it is a lot of work, since you need to make an extension which looks on which device you are, than have an array with all the dimensions.. yuk... Proportional is more easy. If every view is proportional, it looks on every device the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,it ain't so hard indeed.